# Fortran library function crashing when called from visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fortran, g++, gfortran

I have a fortran library which crashes when called from a visual c++ project.  I am hoping for advice on how to resolve the issue.

The fortran library is Arpack (http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/), which I have complied using gfortran targeting x64.  I then created the .dll and .lib files using Mingw.

I am using visual c++ (visual studio 2013) to call the fortran library from a x64 project.  The code compiles correctly, and when I step through with the debugger I can see that the function dsaupd is being called successfully a number of times, with its variables being updated after each call.  On the 5th call to dsaupd, the program crashes with exit code 0.

The c++ function calling the Fortran method is:

```
void arpack_shiftinvert::solve()
{

int IDO = 0;
INFO = 0;


bool continueLoop = true;
while(continueLoop){

    //call arpack function for shift-inverted lanczos algorithm
    dsaupd_(&IDO, &BMAT, &N, WHICH, &NEV, &TOL, RESID, &NCV, V, &LDV, IPARAM, IPNTR, WORKD, WORKL, &LWORKL, &INFO);

    switch (IDO)
    {

    case -1:

        std::cout << "IDO = " << IDO << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 * N; i++){
            std::cout << "WORKD[" <<i << "] = " << WORKD[i] <<"\n";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            WORKD[i + IPNTR[1]-1] = (1+i)*WORKD[i + IPNTR[0]-1];
        }

        break;
    case 1:

        std::cout << "IDO = " << IDO << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 * N; i++){
            std::cout << "WORKD[" << i << "] = " << WORKD[i] << "\n";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            WORKD[i + IPNTR[1]-1] = (1+i)*WORKD[i + IPNTR[2]-1];
        }

        break;
    case 2:

        std::cout << "IDO = " << IDO << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 * N; i++){
            std::cout << "WORKD[" << i << "] = " << WORKD[i] << "\n";
        }

        memcpy(&WORKD[IPNTR[1] - 1], &WORKD[IPNTR[0] - 1], N * 8);

    default:
        continueLoop = false;
    }
} 


dseupd_(&RVEC, &HOWMNY, SELECT, D, Z, &LDZ, &SIGMA, &BMAT, &N, WHICH, &NEV,     &TOL, RESID, &NCV, V, &LDV, IPARAM, IPNTR, WORKD, WORKL, &LWORKL, &INFO);
std::cout << "Eigenvalues:\n";
for (int i = 0; i < NEV; i++){
    std::cout << D[i] << "\n";
}
}
```

The c++ header is:

```
extern "C" {
void __stdcall dsaupd_(int *IDO, char *BMAT, int *N, char *WHICH, int *NEV,     double *TOL, double* RESID, int *NCV, double *V, int* LDV, int *IPARAM, int     *IPNTR, double *WORKD, double *WORKL, int *LWORKL, int *INFO); 
void __cdecl dseupd_(bool *RVEC, char *HOWMNY, bool *SELECT, double *D, double *Z, int *LDZ, double *SIGMA, char *BMAT, int *N, char *WHICH, int *NEV, double *TOL, double* RESID, int *NCV, double *V, int* LDV, int *IPARAM, int *IPNTR, double *WORKD, double *WORKL, int *LWORKL, int *INFO);
}



class arpack_shiftinvert
{
public:
arpack_shiftinvert();
~arpack_shiftinvert();

void solve();
}
```

The output on crashing is:

'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Private\F2C\x64\Debug\F2C.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Private\F2C\x64\Debug\arpack_x64.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Private\F2C\x64\Debug\libgfortran-3.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Private\F2C\x64\Debug\libquadmath-0.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Private\F2C\x64\Debug\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Private\F2C\x64\Debug\libwinpthread-1.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~2\Sophos\SOPHOS~1\SOPHOS~2.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'F2C.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\apphelp.dll'
The program '[23368] F2C.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Isn't C++ bool incompatible with C99's bool and int? (I.e., just a byte?)

Comment: I don't see any evidence of a crash. The program appears to have run to completion and exited successfully.

Comment: @Vladimir F I'm unsure about the compatibility of bool, but isn't that irrelevant to the function dsaupd as it doesn't take bool parameters.  The integer values appear to be recognised by dsaupd, and IDO changes as it should during the while loop.

Comment: dseupd takes bools. Also, why is one stdcall and one cdecl?

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I don't think the program ran to completion successfully since it terminates during a call to the dsaupd function (found using debugger).  This should not happen - the program should exit the while loop and call dseupd before terminating.

Comment: @Vladimir F yes, you are right dseupd takes bools, but the program doesn't get that far at the moment.  Your comment may help with the dseupd function call.  I was experimenting with cdecl and stdcall as different websites indicates one or the other should be used.  I have not seen any difference in behaviour using either, but do not fully understand what the result of using the "wrong" one would be

Comment: Using wrong calling conventions will lead to a certain crash.

Comment: I have resolved the problem.  @Igor Tandetnik, you were correct the program wasn't crashing.  Adding std::cin >>x to the end of the program caught it before it closed, and showed the error message "on entry to dgemv parameter number 6 had an illegal value".  I had not initialised the integer LDV which caused the BLAS routine dgemv called within dsaupd to exit the program.